# AngularJS - How to make a selection of at least one of the checkboxes required in this code?

Tags: angularjs

How to make a selection of at least one of the checkboxes (Mon - Sun) **required if first radio button selected** (in html markup, without calling any function)?

**Screenshot**
[image]
**HTML code fragment (simplified for this question)**

```
<input type="radio" name="dailyOption" 
       ng-model="vm.reportSchedule.DailyOption" value="FollowingDays">

<label ng-repeat="(day, bool) in vm.reportSchedule.DailyRunOnDays">
    <input type="checkbox" name="dailyRunOnDays" 
           ng-model="vm.reportSchedule.DailyRunOnDays[day]">{{day}}
</label>

<input type="radio" name="dailyOption" 
       ng-model="vm.reportSchedule.DailyOption" value="EveryWeekday">

<input type="radio" name="dailyOption" 
       ng-model="vm.reportSchedule.DailyOption" value="RepeatAfterDays">
```

**The model**

```
vm.reportSchedule
{
  "AppId": "ReportScheduleId",
  "Today": "2017-04-25T12:53:00Z",
  "UserId": 7466897,
  "ScheduleId": null,
  "Name": null,
  "Description": null,
  "Type": "Daily",
  "StartSchedule": "2017-04-25T12:53:00Z",
  "StopSchedule": "2017-04-25T12:53:00Z",
  "NextRunTime": null,
  "LastRunTime": null,
  "Permission": {
    "FullAccess": true,
    "View": true,
    "Create": true,
    "Update": true,
    "Delete": true
  },
  "RunEveryHours": 1,
  "RunEveryMinutes": 1,
  "DailyOption": "RepeatAfterDays",
  "MonthlyOption": "CalendarDate",
  "DailyRunOnDays": {
    "Mon": false,
    "Tue": false,
    "Wed": false,
    "Thu": false,
    "Fri": false,
    "Sat": false,
    "Sun": false
  },
  "WeeklyRunOnDays": {
    "Mon": false,
    "Tue": false,
    "Wed": false,
    "Thu": false,
    "Fri": false,
    "Sat": false,
    "Sun": false
  },
  "RepeatAfterDays": 1,
  "RepeatAfterWeeks": 1,
  "RepeatMonths": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ng-required` directive on your checkbox testing wheather there are some checked value on your object, if so, it's not required anymore, like this `ng-required="!vm.some(vm.reportSchedule.DailyRunOnDays)"`.

Template:

```
<input type="radio" name="dailyOption" 
       ng-model="vm.reportSchedule.DailyOption" value="FollowingDays">

<label ng-repeat="(day, bool) in vm.reportSchedule.DailyRunOnDays">
    <input type="checkbox" name="dailyRunOnDays" 
           ng-model="vm.reportSchedule.DailyRunOnDays[day]"
           ng-required="!vm.some(vm.reportSchedule.DailyRunOnDays)">
    {{day}}
</label>
```

Controller:

```
vm.some = function(obj){
    obj= obj|| {};
    return Object.keys(obj).some(function (key) { return obj[key]; });
};
```

You may also want to add the first radi to the conditional of `ng-required`:

```
vm.reportSchedule.DailyOption == FollowingDays && !vm.some(vm.reportSchedule.DailyRunOnDays)
```

Answer (score 0):

I give you 2 posibilities.

If you want hide/show the checkboxes depending on radio button you can use ng-if directive binded to the boolean value.

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-if="vm.reportSchedule.DailyOption ===true" name="dailyRunOnDays" 
           ng-model="vm.reportSchedule.DailyRunOnDays[day]">
```

If you want disable the checkboxes depending on radio button you can use ng-class.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-class="{disabled: vm.reportSchedule.DailyOption === false}" name="dailyRunOnDays" 
           ng-model="vm.reportSchedule.DailyRunOnDays[day]">
```

Comment: Sam, I dont want to hide or disable them, I want to... [the title of my post] :)